# Can TFS 2010 Workflow-based team build get Code Coverage results?

Tags: workflow, code-coverage, tfsbuild

Using Workflow to create a build I'd like for the build quality to change depending if the current code coverage threshold is met.  I have everything set up but the condition to check the coverage percentages.

Is there a way to test if CodeCoveragePercentCovered > vMinThreshold?  Once I figure this out, setting the build qualities is simple.

Answer (score 2):

It's not part of the default Team Build 2010 functionality.
You would need to customize the build proces template and build your own activity to do this.